# Aircraft navigation

Tags: kinematics, velocity

What is the significance of converting aircraft body axis velocity components into earth axis to relate the same with airspeed (Measured from Pitot tube)?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would ask your question in Aviation Stack Exchange http://aviation.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

You can not calculate more than one dimension at a time. This is because velocity can only go in either a positive or negative direction. That is why the vectors in 2 dimensional kinematics must broken up. Then they are covered back using either Pythagorean theorem or trigonometry.